# How do we pronounce the 's' in 'has the' regarding American Accent?

Tags: pronunciation, american-accent

Should it be pronounced as /z/ or /s/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's is pronounced like the *z* in *zebra*.

When *have* means "to be obligated or forced to do X", the pronunciation can change.  The *v* in *have* can be pronounced like the *f* in *fly*, and the *s* in *has* can be pronounced like the *s* in *sand*.

Comment: Please give some examples of your situation "to be obligated or forced to do X"

Comment: Examples: I have to leave now, she has to go to court tomorrow, they have to go to the store later since they are out of food, employees have to stop stealing.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pronounced /z/.

Normally when an "s" initiates a word or syllable, it is pronounced /s/, and when the word or syllable ends in "s" it is pronounced as /z/.